# Where can I find some good tutorials to learn object orientated programming particularly for php?

Tags: php, oop

I've been looking to improve my programming habits and I heard that OO is the way to go. 
Also I'd much prefer online tutorials over books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few good tutorials from the PHP guys themselves.

- [PHP 101 (part 7): The Bear Necessities](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/638)
- [The OO Evolution of PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1717-The-OO-Evolution-of-PHP)
- [Using Objects to Create an Application](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1240-Using-Objects-to-Create-an-Application)

Answer (score 3):

Learning how to use classes, methods, and attributes is not sufficient for making you a good object oriented programmer. The other (and usually much more difficult) part is understanding how to solve problems in an object-oriented way.

It's a bit like chess: Even if you have memorized the rules perfectly, it does not mean you automatically are a good chess player. You still need to learn a about strategy and gather a lot of experience.

I haven't found a good web tutorial on how to become a good object-oriented programmer. The topic is too large to be covered within just a few web pages. You are probably better off reading a book on the subject. It doesn't even have to be specific to php, most OO pricinples can be applied to many different OO languages.

Once you have learned the basics of OO programming, I'd also recommend reading a book on design patterns such as the classic [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-patterns-elements-reusable-object-oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1238931499&sr=1-1) by Gamma et al. or the more casual [Head-First Design patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124).

Comment: I read the whole book 'HF Des.P' and must conclude that although it was a good book, it wasn't an excellent book. I liked the relaxed style and graphics but too much is too much. 3.5stars/5 :) not very essential reading

Comment: I have not found anything online that really teaches oop paradigm truly. Lots of them focus on the syntax and semantics of classes, but don't dig much deeper.

Answer (score 2):

- [OO Tips](http://www.ootips.org/)
- [PHP Classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/)
- [OOP in PHP](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Object-Oriented-Programming-in-PHP/)
- and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=object%20oriented%20programming%20using%20php&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&hs=qGl&start=70&sa=N&cts=1238930053986) of course!

*OO is not a language-depended concept.*

Answer (score 1):

Неге is nice book which shows OOP in practice. You can download the sources from website and look what the book is about.

http://objectorientedphp.com/

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start is the [PHP Classes and Objects](http://php.net/zend-engine-2.php) manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Although the jury is out on certification, you could do far worse than attend a [Zend course](http://www.zend.com/en/services/certification/php-5-certification/).

Answer (score 0):

Not to be mean to Php, because it's quite good to get stuff done and fast, but Object Oriented Php is a non feature in my book, it's more productive to use Php as a procedural language, after all that's what it was made for, OOP is quite poor compared to other languages, same way I'd not use OOP with Perl either, if you want to learn OOP, which I totally recommend you use Ruby or Objective-C.

Anyways can't link but try googling for OMG (Object Management Group), they have tutorials and info about OOP on their site

Answer (score 0):

Some recommend "[PHP in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394753)" by Manning.